# Spring-boot app start fails in Intellij BeanInstantiationException - works in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, intellij-idea

### **Made some progress! See Edit#2 below.**

I have a Spring-boot app, using annotations from *Spring-boot*, *Lombok* and *Mapstruct*.
Application parameters are defined in an application.yml file and in a build-dev.properties.
One of the class is annotated with `@Configuration` and contains the following code:

```
@Configuration
public class CentOriginSpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LoggingCentOriginApiConfig oriWsClientConfiguration(
            final CentOriginConfiguration config) {
        return new LoggingCentOriginApiConfig(config.getBaseUrl(), config.getContext(),
                config.getLogin(), config.getPassword(), false);
    }

    @Bean
    public OriCalendarPubResource OriCalendarPubResource(
            final LoggingCentOriginApiConfig config) {
        return new JerseyClientFactory<>(OriCalendarPubResource.class, config).get();
    }
}
```

The class `CentOriginConfiguration` (in the parameter of the first method) is the base `@Configuration` class of the application.

When I start this application in Intellij, I have the following error:

```
2020-09-30 09:45:22.189 ERROR 19452 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatStarter                : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'confirmEmailSessionListener': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'emailService'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'emailServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'voieFacade'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'centOriginFacadeImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'calendarFacade'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'calendarFacadeImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'calendarResource'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'OriCalendarPubResource' defined in class path resource [com/ed/sco/nat/ts/ori/config/cent/CentOriginSpringConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ed.sco.nat.ori.api.rest.OriCalendarPubResource]: Factory method 'OriCalendarPubResource' threw exception; 
nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**When I start the same application using Eclipse it's working.**

I *suspect* the `final LoggingCentOriginApiConfig config`  to be empty, and that would mean that the first @Bean method of the class is either not called before or the top configuration class `CentOriginConfiguration` is itself empty (simple class, see below). But I'm unable to confirm/invalidate that.

What I tried:

- --debug option of Spring, but I'm unable to find usefull information to help me
- Debugger but too many informations, I couldn't find usefull ones
- Adding various `@Autowired` in `CentOriginSpringConfiguration` (to get the top Configuration first) but nothing changed
- Comparison with Eclipse (in Debug mode) => that's how I saw that the config object in `OriCalendarPubResource()` method was empty

---

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("api.cent-origin")
public class CentOriginConfiguration {
    private String baseUrl;
    private String context;
}
```

build-dev.properties:

```
# Configuration
build.api.cent-origin.base-url=http://localhost
build.api.cent-origin.context=/cent-origin-api-mock/api
```

---

Versions info:

```
<spring.boot.version>2.1.7.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
<jaxrs.version>2.1</jaxrs.version>
<jersey.version>2.27</jersey.version>
<mapstruct.version>1.4.0.CR1</mapstruct.version>
<lombok.version>1.18.12</lombok.version>
```

==============

### Edit 1

I tried to annotate the class `CentOriginSpringConfiguration` with `@EnableConfigurationProperties()` ; and adding an autowired field:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CentOriginConfiguration.class)
public class CentOriginSpringConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private CentOriginConfigurationconfig;

    @Bean
    public LoggingCentOriginApiConfig oriWsClientConfiguration() {
        return new LoggingCentOriginApiConfig(config.getBaseUrl(), config.getContext(),
                config.getLogin(), config.getPassword(), false);
    (...)
}
```

Then I get this error:

```
Field config in com.ed.sco.nat.ts.ori.config.cent.CentOriginSpringConfigurationrequired a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - centOriginConfiguration: defined in file [D:/projects/tso/backend/target/classes/com/ed/sco/nat/ts/ori/config/cent/CentOriginConfiguration.class]
    - api.cent-origin-com.ed.sco.nat.ts.ori.config.cent.CentOriginConfiguration: defined in null
```

=> Using a qualifier I could resolve this but then I got again the first error **BeanInstantiationException**.

============== ==============

### Edit 2

After more test I'm now sure the startup fails because the `@ConfigurationProperties` class is empty:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("api.cent-origin")
public class CentOriginConfiguration {
    private String baseUrl;
    private String context;
}
```

In the main class of the application, we configure our app as follow:

```
public static SpringApplicationBuilder prepareBuilder(final SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.bannerMode(Banner.Mode.CONSOLE)
         .properties("spring.config.additional-location=" + getAdditionnalLocation()) // file:${services.home}/conf/ts-backend/
         .properties("spring.config.name=ts-backend,application")
         .sources(TsApplication.class);
}
```

My configuration is stored in 2 files:

- *application.yml* in root => this one is read & working. I tested by hard coding my missing props from class `CentOriginConfiguration` inside and then the configuration was resolved and the app started
- *ts-backend.properties* stored in the "additional-location"

This property file is:

```
api.cent-origin.base-url=http://localhost
api.cent-origin.context=ts-backend
```

=> The problem now is to understand why the `@ConfigurationProperties` class is **empty**.

Comment: did you put the annotation EnableConfigurationProperties ?

Comment: @JEY I just tried this, see my edit #1 above.

Comment: Please compare classpath in IDEA and Eclipse. Probably there is some difference.

Comment: @y.bedrov I did that, I couldn't find any difference. And the dependencies are coming from Maven. And I'm using the same external JDK in both IDE to run the App.

Comment: What version of spring-boot are you using. If it's 2.2 or greater remove the EnableCOnfigurationProperties and the Component on CentOriginConfiguration